# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded(…)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to place an image in a 'frame_inner' but when i try to upload the image i get the error, and i can't figure out what is wrong with it..

The div called 'frame__inner' is already clickable but every time i click on in the error pops up

HTML:

```
<div id="storyboard">
      <div class="frame">  
        <div class="frame__outer"> 
          <div class="frame__inner">
            <div class="uploader" onclick="$('#filePhoto').click()">
               <img src=""/>
               <input type="file" name="userprofile_picture"  id="filePhoto" />
            </div>
            </div>
          <div class="upper__content">
           <button class="settings"></button>
            <div class="icon-bar">
             <a href="#" class="close_btn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <a href="#" class="add__btn"> <div class="add__image"></div> </a>
               <a href="#" class="remove__btn"> <div class="remove__image"></div> </a>
          </div> 
           <button class="trash"></button>
            <div class="number">1</div> 
          </div>
           <div class="frame_content">
            <div class="mic"></div>

             <div class="frame__titel">
               <span><textarea placeholder="Voice-over:" id="text" rows="2" ></textarea></span>
              </div>
              <form>
                <div class="frame__tekst">
                  <div class="run"></div>
                  <p>
                  <textarea rows="10" cols="45" placeholder="Animatie:"></textarea>
                  </p>
                  </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="frame">
            <!--   <div type="button" class="remove__button"> - </div> -->
       <div type="button" class="add__button"> 
         <div class="btn__wrapper"> + Nieuwe frame</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    'use strict';
    /* global Modernizr:true, fullpage:true, parseInt:true */
    var _this = this,
        _body = $('body'),
        _win = $(window),
        _doc = $(document),
        btn = $('#btn');



    _this.addClickFunction = function() {
            var i = 1;

            _doc.on('click', '.settings', function() {});
            _doc.on('click', '.close_btn', function() {});
            _doc.on('click', '.add__button', function() {
                (i++);
                $('#storyboard .frame').last().before($('<div class="frame"> ' + '<div class="frame__outer"> ' + '<div class="frame__inner">' + '<div class="uploader" onclick="$("#filePhoto").click()">' + '<img src=""/>' + '<input type="file" name="userprofile_picture"  id="filePhoto" />' + '</div>' + '</div>' + '<div class="upper__content">' + '<div class="settings"></div>' + '<div class="icon-bar">' + '<a href="#" class="close_btn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>' + '<a href="#" class="add__btn"> <div class="add__image"></div> </a>' + '<a href="#" class="remove__btn"> <div class="remove__image"></div> </a>' + '</div>' + '<button class="trash"></button>' + '<div class="number">' + i + '</div>' + '</div>' + '<div class="frame_content">' + '<div class="mic"></div>' + '<div class="frame__titel">' + '<span><textarea placeholder="Voice-over:" id="text" rows="2" ></textarea></span>' + '</div>' + '<form>' + '<div class="frame__tekst">' + '<div class="run"></div>' + '<p>' + '<textarea rows="10" cols="45" placeholder="Animatie:"></textarea>' + '</p>' + '</div>' + '</form>' + '</div>' + '</div>' + '</div>'));
            });
        };

        _this.handleImage = function(e) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(event) {
                $('.uploader img').attr('src', event.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
        };
```

Comment: Can you print the error lines? You certainly have long nested calls.

Comment: @Someone There is nothing else 'closeNav', i guess i need the HTML click function: ' onclick="$('#filePhoto').click(); ' inside my jquery?

Comment: Idk your objective, the problem is cause you've long nested calls, e.g., you're entering in many calls, and the browser limits the size of followed calls you can do, e.g., run this: `(function a() { a() })()`, and you'll get the same error you got, because this function calls itself everytime.

Comment: On each function call you do, plus active scopes, and plus memory locations for these calls.

Comment: I got the objective, but, again, can you print the complete error? Show the related lines? Please also show the part related to this error, e.g., the place where you handle the click event of the uploader.

Comment: The error is way to big to upload... the part that is getting an error is the click function in the frame__inner, i just cannot understand why i am getting the error, and it is hard for me to explain..

Comment: Can you show the part where you handle the click event of this element, then?

Comment: @Someone
Press on the big white box and u can get the option to upload the image but when u do it, it gives the error and can't see the image

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aw9mgwxb/

Comment: Well, I think this is a bug in jQuery, if you check the console all calls are related to jQuery's script.

Comment: Well what can i do about it? is it updated?

Comment: Idk much about jQuery, but certainly someone will come here soon